# In jQuery, select parent and find next element

Tags: jquery

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td class="cell">
            <a data-action="open-details" data-type="fields" href="#">Click</a>
        </td>
        <td class="cell">
            <a data-action="open-details" data-type="images" href="#">Click</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="d-none fields">
        <td>Details</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="d-none images">
        <td>Details</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cell">
            <a data-action="open-details" data-type="fields" href="#">Click</a>
        </td>
        <td class="cell">
            <a data-action="open-details" data-type="images" href="#">Click</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="d-none fields">
        <td>Details</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="d-none images">
        <td>Details</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How can I remove the `d-none` class if I click on the Click button ?

This is what I've tried so far:

```
$('[data-action="open-details"]').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    var datasType = $(this).data('type');
    $('.fields, .images').addClass('d-none');
    $(this).parent().parent().find('tr .' + datasType).removeClass('d-none');
});
```

But when I click on the button, it doesn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After getting to the surrounding `<tr>` of the clicked element, use `.next()` and `.nextElementSibling` to get the next two `<tr>`s after it, after which you can test to see which one matches the class you're looking for.

```js
$('[data-action="open-details"]').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const datasType = $(this).data('type');
    $('.fields, .images').addClass('d-none');
    const nextTr = $(this).closest('tr').next()[0];
    [nextTr, nextTr.nextElementSibling]
      .find(tr => tr.matches('.' + datasType))
      .classList.remove('d-none');
});
```

```css
.d-none {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td class="cell">
            <a data-action="open-details" data-type="fields" href="#">Click</a>
        </td>
        <td class="cell">
            <a data-action="open-details" data-type="images" href="#">Click</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="d-none fields">
        <td>Details</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="d-none images">
        <td>Details</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cell">
            <a data-action="open-details" data-type="fields" href="#">Click</a>
        </td>
        <td class="cell">
            <a data-action="open-details" data-type="images" href="#">Click</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="d-none fields">
        <td>Details</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="d-none images">
        <td>Details</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Or with only jQuery methods

```js
$('[data-action="open-details"]').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const datasType = $(this).data('type');
    $('.fields, .images').addClass('d-none');
    const nextTr = $(this).closest('tr').next();
    nextTr.add(nextTr.next())
      .filter((_, tr) => $(tr).is('.' + datasType))
      .removeClass('d-none');
});
```

```css
.d-none {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td class="cell">
            <a data-action="open-details" data-type="fields" href="#">Click</a>
        </td>
        <td class="cell">
            <a data-action="open-details" data-type="images" href="#">Click</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="d-none fields">
        <td>Details</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="d-none images">
        <td>Details</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cell">
            <a data-action="open-details" data-type="fields" href="#">Click</a>
        </td>
        <td class="cell">
            <a data-action="open-details" data-type="images" href="#">Click</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="d-none fields">
        <td>Details</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="d-none images">
        <td>Details</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hello, how can I select just the next one and not all the element please ? Thanks.

Comment: Selecting only the next one means that only `<tr class="d-none fields">` could be selected, which sounds wrong. Don't you want to select the one that matches the `data-type` clicked on, regardless of whether it's right next to the clicked `<tr>` or not?

Comment: I need to select the next `tr.fields` or `tr.images` based on witch button is clicked. But with your actual code, all my `tr.fields` or `tr.images` will be affected.

Comment: I only see one `tr.fields` and one `tr.images` that exist

Comment: Yes but it was juste a part of the code.

Comment: Please post a [MCVE] illustrating the problem